# Why is MySQL (still) not taken seriously as a DBMS by many developers?

Tags: mysql, database, sql

In the past years, I've run into remarks about MySQL not being a DBMS to take seriously by some developers. I've been a MySQL user for quite some time now and I have trouble figuring out why some developers are so much against MySQL. While I'm beginning to believe part of these remarks are true, but only to a small degree, I'm wondering about the real reasons as to why some still think MySQL is inferior.

I concurr that I found check constraints to be missing and BOOLEANs to constrain to an INTEGER in the range of a TINYINT instead of to TRUE and FALSE. Additionally there are some CURRENT_TIMESTAMP issues that I don't like. But are these enough arguments to tout MySQL as an inferior DBMS? What are the real reasons here - if they exist?

Comment: I see SO isn't for discussions, I'll rather post this into a newsgroup. Interesting question nontheless.

Comment: yeah. Maybe it's more suitable on http://programmers.stackexchange.com (no guarantees though, I'm not familiar with the rules over there)